# Does function return break the loop, and dispose of variables in memory?

Tags: c#, function, foreach, return, break

If you are writing a function with a return value, and on one of the code paths you have a foreach, does 'return' also perform 'break'? This one is a little different because it has nested loops.

This is the particular snippet I am talking about. I just want to get out if any criteria has been matched:

```
protected bool SearchMultiples(decimal i)
{
    bool bl = false;
    foreach (var sl in ht.Values)
    {
        foreach (var v in al)
        {
            if (decimal.Parse(v.ToString()) > i)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                if (v.ToString() == i.ToString())
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return bl;
}
```

I have done some searching but I couldn't find anything quite like this. The closest thing I could find was that somebody suggested using a for loop, but that still doesn't answer the question. I realize the statement will return whatever value occurs at that point in the code block, but does it dispose of its data in memory and cease to function?

Why is this important for me? 
I am experimenting with multi-threading for the first time. The application is a prime number finder. This snipit is meant to eliminate large numbers if they are a multiple of a smaller prime. when I find a prime I create a new typed list just for that prime and then fill in the list with p=prime (p*n1,p*n2, p*n3...).
I have to create a list for each prime because I found out that you can't store more than 2GB of info in a single typed list.
then each list goes into a hashtable as a dictionary item. 
The base algorithm is still very rudimentary, but I am working on adding in all of the shortcut rules of division to speed it up.

Comment: Well, did you try and observe what happens?

Comment: `return` transfers control out of the current method/procedure and back to the caller.  So yes, it also breaks out of all control-of-flow structures in the current method. (well, *except* for a `try..finally`, I guess)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, returning from the method will exit from the for loop as well.  It should be fairly easy to write a trivial test to verify...

Answer (score 4):

Just to give you a hint of what's going under hood. C# gets compiled to [CIL (Common Intermediate Language)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) which gets compiled to native code:

> Upon execution of a CLI assembly, its code is passed through the runtime's JIT compiler to generate native code. Ahead-of-time compilation may also be used, which eliminates this step, but at the cost of executable-file portability.

So your source (condition) gets compiled to something like this:

```
IL_0010:  ldloca.s 2
IL_0012:  constrained. [mscorlib]System.Int32
IL_0018:  callvirt instance string object::ToString()
IL_001d:  call valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal::Parse(string)
IL_0022:  ldloc.1 
IL_0023:  call valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal::op_Implicit(int32)
IL_0028:  call bool valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal::op_GreaterThan(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal, valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal)
IL_002d:  brfalse IL_0037
```

So if the condition fails, program goes to "else" branch (which starts at `IL_0032`

```
IL_0032:  br IL_0068
```

Otherwise it breaks the loop -> "jumps" to `IL_0068`, which is first instruction *after* foreach. So break is just *goto* first instruction after loop.

```
IL_0037:  ldloca.s 2
IL_0039:  constrained. [mscorlib]System.Int32
IL_003f:  callvirt instance string object::ToString()
IL_0044:  ldloca.s 1
IL_0046:  constrained. [mscorlib]System.Int32
IL_004c:  callvirt instance string object::ToString()
IL_0051:  call bool string::op_Equality(string, string)
IL_0056:  brfalse IL_005d

IL_005b:  ldc.i4.1 
IL_005c:  ret
```

And `ldc.i4.1` and `ret` together make `return true` and `ret` is defined:

> Return from method, possibly with a value.

So unless there's for example `finally` block still waiting to be processes, function immediately returns.

Comment: While correct and very infornative, it seems to me that the short answer is better in this case. For someone that asks such a trivial question, your answer is way over the top with too much information.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I agree, if there wasn't a simple answer already, I would post simple one... but my point was to provide additional (and I think interesting) information which may or may not interest OP and other people.

Comment: The numbers I am working with on this one are outside of what the .NET framework was designed to handle. Let alone handling multiple threads each each of which was handling a list of multiples, a rule of division, or square root was getting pretty pretty complex and my computers memory filled up so fast (16GB) I was beginning to doubt the built in memory management, but I wanted to get some input on this one.

Answer (score 0):

When you hit a return statement, the function finishes and generally,  code after the return statement is not executed. An exception is when using a try, catch, finally block where code in the finally block will always be run.

Comment: Actually not entirely true. If it's inside try/finally block, the finally block will be run after it, for example.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Nice clarification.